# Rails model error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, model, has-many

I've a component model that has_many :framework. But the :framework don't belongs_to :component, because a framework could belong to lots of components.

I've a controller that returns a json with the frameworks of a concret component:

```
def getFrameworks
    @component = Component.find(params[:component_id])
   respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to components_url }
      format.json { render json: @component.frameworks, location: @component }
   end
end
```

But it gives me the following error:

```
SQLite3::SQLException: no such column: frameworks.component_id: SELECT "frameworks".* FROM "frameworks"  WHERE "frameworks"."component_id" = 298
```

Am I defining wrong the model? What's wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `has_many`needs a `belongs_to`on the related model, for your case 
I believe you want to use the `has_and_belongs_to_many` relation, see the [doc](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html#method-i-has_and_belongs_to_many)

Here is an example of the migration you will need :

```
class CreateComponentsFrameworks < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :components_frameworks, :id => false do |t|
      t.integer :component_id
      t.integer :framework_id
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: So, if I would use `has_and_belongs_to_many`, should I need adding rows to models with the ids of each other? Because it's throwing me a similar error: `SQLite3::SQLException: no such table: components_frameworks: SELECT "frameworks".* FROM "frameworks" INNER JOIN "components_frameworks" ON "frameworks"."id" = "components_frameworks"."framework_id" WHERE "components_frameworks"."component_id" = 296`

Comment: This is because to implement a `has_and_belongs_to_many`relation, you have to create a table to hold the relatoin, in your case it will be a table `components_frameworks` which should not have an id and have 2 columns : `framework_id` and `component_id`. See my updated answer with the migration you need.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the model definitions are indeed wrong, the `has_many` relashionship relies on the fact that the Framework model has a field named component_id. As Component doesn't belong to Framework, you has not defined that field on your model.

To achieve what you want, you could use a `has_and_belongs_to_many` relationship, that models exactly what you seem to want: a component has many frameworks, and a framework can belong to many components

[Link to the Guides](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has_and_belongs_to_many-association)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you are defining wrong your model, you are defining a many to one relation and thats why you are getting the error related the component_id.

[Here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has_many-association) is what you are doing and [here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has_many-through-association) or [here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has_and_belongs_to_many-association) is what you need to do. [This](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#choosing-between-has_many-through-and-has_and_belongs_to_many) also will help you to decide which option use.